# C++ matrix output using ofstream

Tags: c++

I am trying to make the function output numbers in a form of a matrix, not just a line

```
void SaveMatrix(TMatrix* mat){
  ofstream SaveM;
  SaveM.open("Matrix.txt", ios::out);
  if (SaveM.is_open()){
      for (int i=0; i<mat->line; ++i){
          for (int j=0; j<mat->column; ++j){
              SaveM<< mat->m[i][j]<<" ";
          }
      }
  }else{
     cout<<"file is open"<<endl; 
  }
}
```

I tried to put this in the second for-cycle, without a result

```
if(j==mat->column){
    SaveM<<endl;
}
```

The matrix is declared:

```
struct TMatrix {
double* *m;
    int line;
    int column;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

j will never reach mat->column in your inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat->line; i++){
    SaveM << "[";
    for (int j = 0; j < mat->column; j++){
        SaveM << mat->m[i][j]);
        if (j < sizeMatrix - 1){
            SaveM << ", ";
        }
    }
    SaveM << "]" << endl;
}
```